# Catch by refrence in exception handling not giving expected output in c++

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, catch-block

I was going through the differnce between **catch by value/refrence** in Exception handling in c++

Came across this blog https://blog.knatten.org/2010/04/02/always-catch-exceptions-by-reference/

Tried the same and i am not getting the expected output.

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
#include <typeinfo>

class Base {}; 
class Derived: public Base {}; 
int main() 
{ 

try 
{ 
throw Derived();
} 

catch(Base &b) 
{ 
cout<<typeid(b).name();
} 

return 0; 
}
```

The output i am getting is: 4Base
As i am catching by refrence the typeid(b).name() must capture **Derived** ?
or am i doing any thing wrong?

Comment: try to add a virtual function to the base

Comment: The problem is that `Base` and `Derived` are not *polymorphic* types. Add some `virtual` functions (like a `virtual` destructor) and it should work better.

Answer (score 1):

destructor of the base class has to be virtual.

output is "7Derived"

```
#include<iostream> 
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base(){};
}; 
class Derived: public Base {}; 

int main() 
{ 

    try 
    { 
        throw Derived();
    } 

    catch(Base &b) 
    { 
        cout<<typeid(b).name();
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```